# how to configure iis7 on windows 7 home premium to run mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have installed iis on my windows home premium but when requesting my mvc3 site I only get a blank page

I have created a new website running on port 8019
I have enabled all the checkboxes under iis but now all i get is:
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I have configured an application under the default site same error

How do I configure my windows 7 home premium to run mvc 3 apps?
Do I need to install anything?

if

I thought that pointing my website to my code directory would run

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to execute the [ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (aspnet_regiis.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) which configures IIS for running ASP.NET applications.  This is normally necessary if you install IIS after the .NET Framework.

Comment: that was my original thought but I don't see it in my  
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 folder i only find it under 2.0 and since I configured my appliation pool to run 4.0 integrated I tought it was installed. Do I still need to aspnet_regiis.exe ?

Answer (score 1):

My bad 
aspnet mvc 3 was not installed so framework 4.0 was not installed that is why I could not see the aspnet_regiis in my folder